# Function to model mean in Jags

Tags: r, jags

I'm using jags to model engineering inverse problems from a Bayesian framework.
I would like to know if I can include a function to define the mu parameter in the jags model. For example

```
# Define the model:
modelString = "
model {
for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
  myData[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i] ,1/sigma^2 )
  mu[i]=function(c,fi){...}
}
  c  ~ dnorm( 9 , 1/9 )
  fi ~ dnorm( 24 , 1/4 )
}
```

when I include the function I get an error: Error parsing model file:
syntax error on line 6 near "{"

Is there some way to include a function inside the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there is no way to define a new function directly in BUGS/JAGS in the way that you want, because BUGS is not a programming language. You are limited to using the functions and distributions listed in the JAGS user manual, or made available for use by loading external JAGS modules such as runjags or jags-wiener or (currently a small number of) others.

The slightly longer version is that you can define your own functions and distributions in JAGS by writing your own module to specify your desired function/distribution in C++ and then loading that into JAGS. The official JAGS documentation is currently light on details, but there is a tutorial published:

Wabersich, D., and J. Vandekerckhove. 2014. Extending JAGS: a tutorial on adding custom distributions to JAGS (with a diffusion model example).. Behav. Res. Methods 46:15–28. doi:10.3758/s13428-013-0369-3.

This obviously requires familiarity with C++ but it is not that difficult if you are already a C++ coder. Installing the module is much easier if you embed the JAGS extension module within an R package, like the runjags package does (look in the /src directory). If you are not already a C++ coder then best to seek assistance.

Hope that helps,

Matt

——-

Edit: it is also worth saying that there is probably a way of doing what you want in BUGS/JAGS, it is just that what you wanted to implement (writing a function inside the JAGS model) is not a viable solution. If you explain your actual problem in more detail (probably in a new question) then you might get a solution that you had not considered.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Do you think Phyton and PyMC3 handles this problem better?

Comment: I’m not sure. There are a number of different way to fit arbitrary models using MCMC with different strengths/weaknesses depending on what you want to do (and balance between ease of use and flexibility). The only way to have full flexibility is to write the framework and samplers yourself.